# jquery hiddenbox and listbox discount calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, hidden, html

I want to use jQuery to calculate value from listbox and hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="val1" name="albania" value="100000" />
<select class="span6 chosen" id="val2" name="discount" data-placeholder="Choose a       Discount" tabindex="1">
  <option value="" />
  <option value="10" />10
  <option value="20" />20
</select>
```

and I want to write a value in span

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" >Total Value After Discount</label>
  <div class="controls">    
    <span class="help-inline" id="yaz"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basicly I need to calculate discount from the price and show it for the customers. I tried this code:

```
<script>
  $('input["#val2"]').keyup(function() {
    var a = $('input["#val1"]').val();
    var b = $(this).val();
    $("#yaz").text((a * b) / 100 + a);
  });
</script>
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
$('#val2').change(function() {
var a = $('#val1').val();
var b = $(this).val();
$("#yaz").text((parseInt(a) * parseInt(b)) / 100 + parseInt(a));
});
```

You should use `change` event instead of `keyup`

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4gE9w/)**

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use parseInt

```
$("#yaz").text((parseInt(a) * parseInt(b)) / 100 + parseInt(a));
```